# ActiveRecord: SQL injection resistant wheres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

I'm trying to build a miniature engine that will allow a search query to be built up on the fly by user input. I get the column name and the search string in the params, let's assume:

```
params = {:filter_column => "column_name", :filter_string => "search term"}
```

I know that if I were just calling a standard sort of where on my model it would be along the lines of:

```
ModelName.where("column_name LIKE ?", params[:filter_string])
```

The problem I have is I'm trying to compile a list of my filters and then apply them one at a time to the search. Can I build up the where string before I call the where method?

I've tried:

```
ModelName.where("? LIKE ? ", column_name, search_term)
```

without much luck. Any hints, tips or pointers?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try a solution that uses the [Metawhere Gem](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/)

i'm thinking something like:

```
Model.where(params[:filter_column].intern.matches => params[:filter_string])
```

and you can build each one sequentially in it's own condition separated by commas or subsequent calls to where.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Allowing finer grain control was essential. Plus, I felt kind of dirty typing any sql...in this case "LIKE"...

Comment: yeah i haven't used metawhere enough in my own code, but it's pretty great even for little things.  Same guy also recently came out with 'squeel' which seems to be an evolution - haven't looked at it yet but just fyi.

Answer (score -1):

If only you can change the content of `column_name` (i.e. no risk of injection) there's no harm in using

```
ModelName.where("`#{column_name}` LIKE ?", search_term)
```